# Сервер на Go не желает получать некоторые запросы

Tags: golang

Пишу приватный сервер для игры, логин и регистрация работают, но когда я совершаю запрос на "localhost:9090/golangg/uploadGJLevel211.php", то ничего не происходит, и в консоли не отображается информация. Если захожу с браузера, то мне выдает "1", в консоли появляется информация. Почему я не могу совершить запрос из игры?

Вырезанный код:

```go
func listenUploadLevel(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("Новый запрос. Путь:", r.URL.Path)
    r.ParseForm()
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "1")
}

func main() {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("Сервер запущен.")
    http.HandleFunc("/", listenMain)
    http.HandleFunc("/golangg/uploadGJLevel211.php", listenUploadLevel)
    http.HandleFunc("/golangg/accounts/registerGJAccount.php", listenRegisterAccount)
    http.HandleFunc("/golangg/accounts/loginGJAccount.php", listenLoginAccount)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":9090", nil)
}
```

Версия Go:

```
go version go1.10.4 linux/amd64
```

"go env":

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/gdmoonpy/.cache/go-build"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/gdmoonpy/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/lib/go-1.10"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go-1.10/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build042763889=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

ОС: Ubuntu 18.10 amd64.

Comment: Если с браузера работает, то ищите ошибки в клиенте.

Comment: @Ainar-G у меня нет исходного кода игры, она не моя.